# Can't set proper WooCommerce language translation

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, translation

I've set Wordpress' language to my language (`General -> Site Language`) and downloaded latest translations for WooCommerce and uploaded it via FTP but I still see untranslated strings on webpage. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using WP v4.6.1 and WC v2.6.6.

Here I selected WP language (not sure why  `woocommerce-sl_SI` is listed but after selecting the translations were still not there) :

[image]

Here are translations uploaded to server:

[image]

Comment: Are all strings untranslated?

Comment: Yes. I checked for "Add to cart" button string. I checked the `po` file and I can see it is translated, e.g.:

`#: includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php:584
#: includes/class-wc-product-simple.php:48
#: includes/class-wc-product-variation.php:208
msgid "Add to cart"
msgstr "Dodaj v košarico"`

Comment: Do you mind providing the link of your *woocommerce-sl_SI* translation file for possible replication and closer look for troubleshooting?

Comment: Sure: [download here](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/dev/sl/default/export-translations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After installing WordPress version 4.6.1 and WooCommerce version 2.6.6, *both with the default enabled language, English (United States)*, I followed the steps below and had the translation successfully installed and working:

1. Set a language for your WordPress installation

   - Click on the **General** sub-menu item under **Settings** from the **Dashboard** of your WordPress installation, and scroll down to the last edit option available: ***Site Language***;
   - there, select your desired language, here: *Slovenščina*, then, click on the "Save Changes" button in order to effect your modification.

*At this stage, though the language base of your WordPress installation has been updated, you will realise that your WooCommerce pages will still be displayed in it's default initial installation language: English (United States).*

2. Now, hover on your **Dashboard** menu item and click on the **Update Core** (both now displayed in your newly defined WordPress installation language).

   You should already see there a notification about a number of updates available; our focus here is on the available *translation updates*.

   - Scroll down the page and click on the "Update Translations" button under the **Translations** section (all still in your newly defined WordPress installation language) in order to update the language definition for readily modifiable WordPress packages, which includes WooCommerce.

*After a successful update, you may now click on the* **WooCommerce** *menu; everything should be automatically available in your newly defined WordPress installation language (except untranslated strings).*

---

Should you chose to update your WooCommerce language over FTP, do make sure you upload your **`.mo`** and **`.po`** files to the **`plugins`** directory under **`wp-content/languages`** so as to make them readily accessible for use; **NOT** immediately under the **`wp-content/languages`** as shown on your attached screenshot: that accounts for the wrong listing of **`woocommerce-sl_SI`** as an ***installed Core WordPress translations*** *(refer to your first screenshot above; Site Language dropdown list)*.

Uploading both **`.mo`** and **`.po`** files to your **`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages`** instead of the later directory as specified above will equally work.

*Please note: the default installation language will be used for your WooCommerce installation instance should there be no corresponding language set **`.mo`** and **`.po`** files matching your WordPress installation language; either: WordPress is **`sl_SI`**, WooCommerce should equally be **`sl_SI`**.*

Comment: I tried the second solution - uploading to proper directory - and it works! Thank you.

Comment: Yes; you are right; the **`woocommerce-sl_SI.mo`** and **`woocommerce-sl_SI.po`** files for ***Slovenščina*** *(and few other ones)* are not directly accessible from the *WordPress core packages* "Translation Update" unlike ***Slovenčina, Español,*** etc. and therefore requires a manual inclusion at a given stage *(downloading the appropriate corresponding resource from the [WordPress.org WooCommerce translation repository](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce) and or other ones, and uploading into the **right directory**)* for an effective execution. Glad it worked!